# Customer email is required on facebook login

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, facebook

I'm Struggling with magento exeption when im trying to log in via `facebook login and like free` extension in Magento 1.9.1

This is my exeption log. I can see that Customer Email is required, does somebody know how to fix this exeption ?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:26:"Customer email is required";i:1;s:1863:"#0 
appURL/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(76): Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', 'Customer email ...')
#1 appURL/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1122): Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#2 appURL/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#3 appURL/app/code/community/Belvg/FacebookFree/controllers/CustomerController.php(101): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#4 appURL/app/code/community/Belvg/FacebookFree/controllers/CustomerController.php(74): Belvg_FacebookFree_CustomerController->_registerCustomer(Array, Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Session))
#5 appURL/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Belvg_FacebookFree_CustomerController->LoginAction()
#6 appURL/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#7 appURL/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 appURL/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 appURL/app/Mage.class.php(656): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 appURL/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:148:"APPURL/index.php/facebookfree/customer/login/?referer=aHR0cDovL2tpbmdkb21zb2x1dGlvbnMucGwvZnJ5a2FzeS9pbmRleC5waHAvY3VzdG9tZXIvYWNjb3VudC9sb2dpbi8,";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"APPURL/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in `/app/code/community/Belvg/FacebookFree/controllers/CustomerController.php` a Customer model class is called possibly to create a customer object and no email is provided before the `$customer_model->save()` is being called.